# How to find text in a column and saving the row number where it is first found - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following column (column A) named project (rows column is just displaying the row number):

```
rows    project
1       14
2       15
3       16
4       17
5       18
6       19
7       ProjTemp
8       ProjTemp
9       ProjTemp
```

I have an input message box where the user writes the new project name which I want inserted right after the last one. Ex: project 20 will be inserted right after project 19 and before the first "ProjTemp".

My theory was to locate the row number of the first "ProjTemp" and then insert a new row where the project is 20.

I was trying to use the Find function but I'm getting an overflow error (I'm sure I'm getting it because it's finding 3 "ProjTemp" strings and trying to set it to one parameter):

```
Dim FindRow as Range

with WB.Sheets("ECM Overview")
    Set FindRow = .Range("A:A").Find(What:="ProjTemp", _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
end with
```

How do I code this so I only find the row number of the fist "ProjTemp"?
Is there a better way to do this, maybe a loop?

Thanks, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with all those parameters of the `Find` method; but upon shortening it, the following is working for me:

```
With WB.Sheets("ECM Overview")
    Set FindRow = .Range("A:A").Find(What:="ProjTemp", LookIn:=xlValues)
End With
```

And if you solely need the row number, you can use this after:

```
Dim FindRowNumber As Long
.....
FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row
```

Comment: quick question, how would i select that whole row? I keep getting `Select method of Range class failed`

Comment: you simply can use "Sheets(1).Rows(FindRowNumber).Select". Premission is that you saved the rownumber the way mango told above

Comment: @j0chn  I did that and it keeps saying it's out of range still...instead of Sheets(1) though I had Sheets("ECM Overview") just to be completely right about my wording.

Comment: Than I can't help you, sorry.

Comment: Sorry to dredge this question back up, but this answer almost works for me. Is there some reason why the ".Find" will work in a subroutine but not in a function? I created a sub to search a column for a string and it works. But, when I change the sub to a function, the Find never returns a result.

Comment: @ThomDeCarlo I know this is old, but hopefully it'll help someone else. Are you returning the row address from the function? You will need to do this by setting a variable equal to the function and then set the function equal to the row address within the function. Functions return a value while subroutines just carry out a set of instructions.

Answer (score 8):

```
Dim FindRow as Range

Set FindRow = Range("A:A").Find(What:="ProjTemp", _' This is what you are searching for
                   After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _ ' This is saying after the last cell in the_
                                                  ' column i.e. the first
                   LookIn:=xlValues, _ ' this says look in the values of the cell not the formula
                   LookAt:=xlWhole, _ ' This look s for EXACT ENTIRE MATCH
                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _ 'This look down the column row by row 
                                            'Larger Ranges with multiple columns can be set to 
                                            ' look column by column then down 
                   MatchCase:=False) ' this says that the search is not case sensitive

If Not FindRow  Is Nothing Then ' if findrow is something (Prevents Errors)
    FirstRow = FindRow.Row      ' set FirstRow to the first time a match is found
End If
```

If you would like to get addition ones you can use:

```
Do Until FindRow Is Nothing
    Set FindRow = Range("A:A").FindNext(after:=FindRow)
    If FindRow.row = FirstRow Then
        Exit Do
    Else ' Do what you'd like with the additional rows here.

    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use a loop, keep the row number (counter should be the row number) and stop the loop when you find the first "ProjTemp".

Then it should look something like this:

```
Sub find()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim firstTime As Integer
    Dim bNotFound As Boolean

    i = 1
    bNotFound = True

      Do While bNotFound
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "ProjTemp" Then
            firstTime = i
            bNotFound = false
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

1. Since the search position is important you should specify where you start the search. I use `ws.[a1]` and `xlNext` below so my search starts in `A2` of the specified sheet.
2. Some of `Find`s arguments - including `lookat` use the prior search settings. So you should always specify `xlWhole` or `xlPart` to match all or part a string respectively.
3. You can do all you want - including inserting a row, and prompting the user for a new value (my code will suggest 20 if the prior value was 19) without using `Select` or `Activate`

**suggested code**

```
Sub FindEm()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Wb.Sheets("ECM Overview")
Set rng1 = ws.Range("A:A").Find("ProjTemp", ws.[a1], xlValues, xlWhole, , xlNext)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
rng1.EntireRow.Insert
rng1.Offset(-1, 0).Value = Application.InputBox("Please enter data", "User Data Entry", rng1.Offset(-2, 0) + 1, , , , , 1)
Else
MsgBox "ProjTemp not found", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for "projtemp" and then check if the previous one is a number entry (like 19,18..etc..) if that is so then get the row no of that proj temp ....

and if that is not so ..then re-check that the previous entry is projtemp or a number entry ...