# Create VBA to copy and paste data based on specified date

Tags: vba, excel

How do I write a VBA that automatically copies and pastes data from one sheet to another in the same workbook? I have 7 columns: submitter, submitted date, hcp number, hcp name, FRN, exemption type (form type in Sheet B), program type and line numbers.  Sheet A automatically refreshes, so the data is always current. The only caveat is the data pulled into Sheet B must be in real time based on the submitted date. I know I'd have to refresh Sheet B to update its data. That is fine.

[Sheet A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgF1d.png)

[Sheet B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DruQr.png)

For instance:

Today is 4/4/2017. I'd like to pull all data from the 7 columns (from Sheet A) with the submitted date of 4/4/2017, and add them to Sheet B. This must happen when I click refresh all data.

The VBA should pull data submitted on the weekends as well.

This is what I have so far:

```css
Sub Refresh()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Double
    Dim Worksheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim Worksheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim ColumnB As Long
    Dim ColumnC As Long
    Dim ColumnD As Long
    Dim ColumnE As Long
    Dim ColumnF As Long
    Dim ColumnG As Long
    Dim ColumnH As Long
    Dim ColumnI As Long

    Set Worksheet1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AUTOTRACK") ' Change name of sheet if necessary 
    Set Worksheet2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tracking Sheet") ' Change name of sheet if necessary
    ColumnB = 1  ' Change if you want other columns, 1 = A-column, 2 = B etc
    ColumnC = 2
    ColumnD = 3
    ColumnE = 4
    ColumnF = 5
    ColumnG = 6
    ColumnH = 7
    ColumnI = 8

    For i = 1 To Worksheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Worksheet1.Cells(i, ColumnB).Value = DateAdd(
“d”, -1,  Then
            x = Worksheet1.Cells(i, ColumnA).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

The date is incomplete because I don't want to have a date range. It should pull data based on today's date - 1 day. The other problem is the columns don't match. There are 8 in total, column H in Sheet A is not the same in Sheet B.

Comment: You've described what you need, but not what you've tried to achieve it, nor which specific brickwall you're facing. Stack Overflow isn't a "please give me code that does XYZ" code-writing service. Please see [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA - Pulling a value on the same row based on another column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793060/vba-pulling-a-value-on-the-same-row-based-on-another-column)

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Refresh()    
    Worksheets("A").Range("A1:A7").Copy
    Worksheets("B").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End Sub
```

This code copies cells from A1 to A7 in sheetA to SheetB.
You can mention range as you want as source and destination

Answer (score -1):

I'm posting a sample code, it will help you to get the idea to solve the problem.

```
Sub copypaste()

Dim r As Range, filt As Range, d1 As Long, d2 As Long

With Worksheets("sheet1") 
d1 = .Range("F1").Value 
d2= .Range("G1").Value .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=.Range("A1").Column, Criteria1:=">=" & CDate(d1) _ , Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDate (d2)

 = .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

With Worksheets("sheet2") .Cells.Clear filt.Copy .Range("a1").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: Your sample code would be more helpful if it compiled. As it stands this answer is useless.

Comment: I understand the range and source parts of the code, it's pulling information based on a date that confuses me. When I refresh Sheet B, I need the code to only add new data to the sheet.

Comment: Hey JW,, could you please write what is the Criteria to determine New Data Every day other than the Current date.

Comment: So far I have Value = DateAdd ("d", -1...) but I don't know how to specify the rest hence ellipses. The "current date" is the date the form was submitted. Format is xx/xx/xxxx. The data pulled would be the date-1