# Object Required - With wb.Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I was looking for a way to find data in a column and using google i found this page.
[How to find text in a column and saving the row number where it is first found - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910913/how-to-find-text-in-a-column-and-saving-the-row-number-where-it-is-first-found)

and one of the codes i am trying to use what came from that page

```
With WB.Sheets("ECM Overview")
    Set FindRow = .Range("A:A").Find(What:="ProjTemp", LookIn:=xlValues)
End With
```

i have change the code to fit my sheet but i keep getting an Object Required
i try setting the

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
```

but then i just get other goofy errors not sure what im doing wrong here

the code im using for my sheet

```
 With wb.Sheets("RR LOG")
    Set FindRow = .Range("H:H").Find(What:=ProRRnumber, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you may not have set `wb` as anything.

Before the `With` statement, try adding code like:

```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
```

Or, if you want to explicitly assign `wb` to the name of a workbook, try:

```
Set wb = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")
```

Replace `Book1.xlsx` with the name of the workbook you are referencing.