# Find a date in a cell of a different workbook, then return the row number as a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks, the first workbook is for employees to use which generates reports for that week. The second workbook is the one that contains all the data needed to make those reports.

What I am trying to do is find the date of the beginning of the week and do a VLookup on the second workbook to find the week beginning date and return the "row number" of the found cell as a variable that I can use for various other things.

The current code returns *Runtime Error (424): Object Required*.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub SourceFileLookup()

    Dim lookFor As Range
    Dim srchRange As Range

    Dim book2 As Workbook

    Dim book2Name As String
    book2Name = "Report_Data.xlsx"    ' Name of Source File

    Set book2 = Workbooks(book2Name)

    strdate = GetWeekStartDate(Date)
    fdate = Format(strdate, "dd/mm/yy")


    Set lookFor = fdate     ' value to find
    Set srchRange = book2.Sheets("TB").Range("B:B")    ' Search Range

    lookFor = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchRange, 1, False)

    Exit Sub
End Sub

Function GetWeekStartDate(ByVal strdate, Optional ByVal lngStartDay As Long = 2) As String
    GetWeekStartDate = DateAdd("d", _
                   -Weekday(CDate(strdate), lngStartDay) + 1, CDate(strdate))
End Function
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur? 
Can it be that `lookFor` is of the wrong type (`Range`), in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194701.aspx) it specifies `Variant` as return type.

Comment: If you want to return the number of the row you found your result in, `VLookup`might be the wrong approach, since it returns the value of a cell. For finding the row, have a look at [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15911112/4600127).

Answer (score 1):

Vlookup returns the value of that specified cell not the address. Use MATCH to get row of the matching date

```
Application.Match(lookFor, srchRange, 0)
```

Then you can use the row as you want

Answer (score 1):

You only **Set** objects. You would not use Set to assign a date to a variable and the variable should be a `Date` type or a `Variant`. In fact, the `GetWeekStartDate` function is returning a date type value but you are tossing it back and forth as a string and then trying to Set a Range object to it.

```
Sub SourceFileLookup()

    Dim fDate As Date
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim srchRange As Range
    Dim book2Name As String, book2 As Workbook

    book2Name = "Report_Data.xlsx"    ' Name of Source File
    Set book2 = Workbooks(book2Name)

    fDate = GetWeekStartDate(Date)
    Set srchRange = book2.Sheets("TB").Range("B:B")    ' Search Range

    If Application.CountIf(srchRange, fDate) Then
        rw = Application.Match(CLng(fDate), srchRange, 0)

        'rw contains the Row Number of the date
        'you need to do something with rw
    Else
        MsgBox Format(fDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " not found."
    End If

End Sub
```

You stated that you wanted to **return the row number as a variable**. The [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) is the best choice for that but it is best to make sure that it is there with [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) before retrieving the row number.

There was very little in regard to what to do with the row number once you have retrieved it. In the above, it is stored in the `long` type variable `rw`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems to outline what i want nicely, but with this i am getting a Runtime Error (9) Subscript out of range

Comment: My apologies. You should have been looking to match the raw underlying value of the date, not the date itself. See my modification above.

Comment: Thanks for this, Works perfectly. +1

Answer (score -1):

```
set lookFor = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchRange, 1, False)
```